# Zend Framework 1.7 to 1.8 Exception caught by form Method getMaxFileSize does not exist

Tags: php, zend-framework

What cause this error message `"Exception caught by form Method getMaxFileSize does not exist"` after switching from 1.7 version to 1.8 or more

update: Issue produced by code

```
        ->addElement('file', 'avatar', array(
              'required'    => false
            , 'label'       => 'Upload File:'
            , 'destination' => '/data/avatar'
            , 'filters'     => array()
            , 'validators'  => array(
                  array('Extension', false, 'jpg,png,gif')
                , array('Size', false, 102400)
                , array('Count', false, 1)
            )
            , 'decorators' => $this->groupElementDecorators
        ))
```

update2: 
group decorators is just an array

```
$groupElementDecorators = array( 'ViewHelper', 'FormElements', 'File', 'Errors');
```

Comment: You're calling a method that doesn't exist. Whats the code calling it?

Comment: What is `$this`? What means "1.8 or more"? You should use the latest release.

Comment: 1.8 or more means that this happen after switching from 1.7 to any version after 1.8

Comment: If you got a solution for your problem, it would be great to post  the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [issue](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5025), you must be using the following.

```
'validators' => array(
array('Size', false, array('min' => '3', 'max' => '9'))
)
```